# How to extract the information from JSon in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I have Sample Data

```
 set @j = '[{"id": 1, "title": "Mohan"}, 
            {"id": 2, "title": "Rama"}, 
            {"id": 3, "title": "IP Mana"}]';
  Select REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(@j, '$**.*'),"[",""),"]",""),'"','') AS Name_List from  tbl_employee
```

I'm getting Data Like this  :

```
    NameList
 1, Mohan, 2, Rama, 3, IP Mana
```

I'm trying to get output like this :

```
NameList
 1 : Mohan, 2 : Rama, 3 : IP Mana
```

Can any one Suggest me .

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: @GMB MYSQL 8.0.13 but i need to execute in Lower versions also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL 8.0, you can use `json_table()` for this:

```
select id, title
from json_table(
    @j,
    '$[*]'
    columns (id int path '$.id', title varchar(20) path '$.title')
) t;
```

Or if you want the results as a scalar value:

```
select group_concat(id, ' : ', title separator ', ') res
from json_table(
    @j,
    '$[*]'
    columns (id int path '$.id', title varchar(20) path '$.title')
) t;
```

In earlier versions, you would typically use a table of numbers and `json_extract()`:

```
select 
    json_extract(@j, concat('$[', n.n, '].id')) id,
    json_extract(@j, concat('$[', n.n, '].title')) title
from (select 0 n union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3) n
where json_extract(@j, concat('$[', n, ']')) is not null
```

Comment: it is there in the table column how can I implement this in table

Comment: @mohan111: `select t.id, t.title
from mytable x
cross join json_table(
    x.j,
    '$[*]'
    columns (id int path '$.id', title varchar(20) path '$.title')
) t;`

Comment: it is giving me error . I have Employee Column in that JSon Data is there  . Select JSON_EXTRACT(@j, '$**.*') AS Name_List from  tbl_employee

Comment: @mohan111: what is `JSON_EXTRACT(@j, '$**.*')` supposed to be? This does not come from the queries I provided you with.

Comment: I will check with above provided code and rearrange my script and get back to you

Comment: Hi @GMB can you please have a look on my question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61465532/how-to-do-running-subtraction-from-other-column-in-mysql/61465611?noredirect=1#comment108730563_61465611

Comment: Hi @GMB can you please have a look on this  question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61481328/how-to-implement-roll-back-transaction-and-error-message-in-mysql/61481718#61481718

Comment: Hi @GMB can you please have a look : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61530970/how-to-fetch-records-based-on-the-dates-in-mysql?noredirect=1#comment108843802_61530970