# How to do Running subtraction from other column in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have sample Data :

```
Month        Val     Bval
Jan 2020   12000    0
Feb 2020            0
Mar 2020            100
Apr 2020            0
May 2020            500
Jun 2020           1000
```

I want to subtract the column values with beside value column  . Need to get output  like this :

```
Month        Val     Bval
Jan 2020   12000    0
Feb 2020   12000    0
Mar 2020   11900    100
Apr 2020   11900    0
May 2020   11400    500
Jun 2020   10400    1000
```

I have tried with Co related query  :

```
SELECT t.Month,
         t.Bval,
         (SELECT x.val -t.Bval 
            FROM TABLE x
           WHERE x.Month <= t.Month) AS Val
    FROM TABLE t
ORDER BY t.Month
```

Not getting proper result .

Can any one suggest me the suitable way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a self join and aggregation:

```
select t1.Month, sum(t2.Val) - sum(t2.Bval) Val, t1.Bval
from tablename t1 left join tablename t2
on str_to_date(concat(t1.Month, ' 01'), '%b %Y %d') >= str_to_date(concat(t2.Month, ' 01'), '%b %Y %d')
group by t1.Month, t1.Val, t1.Bval
order by str_to_date(concat(t1.Month, ' 01'), '%b %Y %d')
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=1a45e1957e35374528592e7adc5dd2d5).
Results:

```
> Month    |   Val | Bval
> :------- | ----: | ---:
> Jan 2020 | 12000 |    0
> Feb 2020 | 12000 |    0
> Mar 2020 | 11900 |  100
> Apr 2020 | 11900 |    0
> May 2020 | 11400 |  500
> Jun 2020 | 10400 | 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (first_value(val) over (order by month) -
        sum(bval) over (order by month)
       ) as new_val
from t;
```

This assumes that `month` is really a date or something that is ordered in a sensible way.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c827ff9e92d6980313363489c0281a3f) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: @mohan111 . . . MySQL has supported window functions since the release of 8.0 in April 2018.

Comment: I have tried with your code  it is  not giving value when BVAL is 0 it should show the same Record  but it is showing NULL

Comment: I need to have backward compatibility also means below  8.0 also