# How to implement Roll Back Transaction and Error Message in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I Have sample procedure  .

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sample_procedure ` 
(
IN IDIn bigint(20),
IN MainIDIn bigint(20),
IN NameIn  varchar(20)
)
 READS SQL DATA
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
INSERT INTO tbl_DEPT
(
ID,
Name)
Select 1,'Mohan';

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM tbl_emp  te  WHERE te.ID = IDIn) THEN 
INSERT INTO tbl_emp
(
MainID,
Name) 
VALUES (MainIDIn,
        NameIn);
ELSE 
IF  EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM tbl_emp  te  WHERE te.ID = IDIn) THEN 
  UPDATE tbl_emp  
  set
    MainID =MainIDIn,
    name = NameIn
  WHERE te.ID= IDIn;
  END IF;
  END IF;
END
```

**Call sample_procedure(1,2,Sampl123)**

I'm just sending some  irrelevant Data into the Procedure so that procedure gets  failed  . But how  we need to implement   roll back means  it should  come to the starting  state with out Inserting Records into the  tbl_DEPT also.

IN T-SQL we will have

```
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    BEGIN TRY
        SET @OUT = "success";
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
        set @out = 'not success';
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END CATCH
END
```

this  kind  of TRY CATCH blocks  and  to capture  Error

```
 "ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
    ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity"
```

In the same way in MYSQL I'm looking  for TRY CATCH and ROLL BACK Mechanism .

IF Procedure fails  it should  ROLL BACK and  Not to load in any of the table .

Can any one  Suggest me  in MYSQL.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql does not use try/catch. If uses handlers, e.g. the EXIT handler that will terminate the execution of the SP:

```
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 
BEGIN 
    ROLLBACK;
    -- other logic
END;
```

There are other type of handlers as well.

Comment: Is any other more informative way  to handle  @peter

Comment: You can get the error message inside the handler if you are using 5.7 or later version. e.g., GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1;
         @p1 = MESSAGE_TEXT; You can save the error message to log table if you want or return to client side.

Comment: I will check other things  also and let you know